# `apachectl status` fails after enabling "mod_ssl"

Tags: debian, apache2

After enabling "mod_ssl" and adding my first VirtualHost for port 443 I was puzzled to learn that `apachectl status` no longer works even though "mod_status" was working before. Apache is however running fine and serving all requests.

Comment: I am posting this since I did not find a related issue when searching the internet. Hope this will make it easier for others help the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realized that I did not enable the "default-ssl" site. So after enabling it and doing a `apachectl graceful` issuing `apachectl status` started to provide the exptected information again.